# Resize a table proportional to regular size (not textwidth)

Tags: tables, resize

I have a couple tables in my paper. I would like them both to be scaled down a bit, to approx. 85% of regular size.

There are many posts on how to do this using `\resizebox`, but they all use `\textwidth` as the basis, something like:

```
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \centering
  \resizebox{0.85\textwidth}{!}{
        \caption{Table caption}
        \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
          \hline
          $t_0~(MeV\cdot fm^3 ) $ & $t_3~(MeV\cdot fm^6)$ & $v_0/\mu~(MeV\cdot fm)$ & $1/\mu~(fm)$\\
          \hline
          $$ -497.726 & $17270$ & $-166.924$ & $0.45979$\\
          \hline
        \end{tabular}
   }
\end{table}
```

But with this code, it scales the table to be 85% of the text width. This is great, except that I have multiple tables of different widths and I need them all to have the same font size so it doesn't look ridiculous. If I used the above code for each table, all the tables would become the same width, meaning that tables that are naturally wide would have a small font size, and tables that are naturally narrow would have a huge font size.

Is there any way to use `\resizebox` with a size relative to the table's natural size, instead of the `\textwidth`?

Comment: `\resizebox{0.85\width}{...}` would do, but why not using `\small`?

Comment: I found this on page 8 of `grfguide.pdf` (which is what the command `texdoc graphics` gave me): `\scalebox{.85}{...}`.

Comment: scaling tables is _evil_!!! just use `\small\begin{tabular}....` that way you get consistent document font sizes not some arbitrary scaling

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the problem is, I want my table to be as large as possible while still fitting within the page. If I use `\small`, it will bee too small and leave empty unused space on the page. I need finer control over the size, somewhere between small and normal.

Comment: at 10pt, `\small` is `\fontsize{9pt}{11pt}\selectfont`, so perhaps you want `\fontsize{9.5pt}[10.7pt}\selectfont`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks, that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use

```
\resizebox{0.85\width}{<contents>}
```

because in this context `\width` refers to the width of `<contents>`.

Anyway this shouldn't contain the caption, because captions should have the same size across the document. Moreover, you have no real control on the outcome.

It's better using a font size command. Possibly act on `\tabcolsep`, there are several examples on the site.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,caption}

\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{\cdot}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering\footnotesize
\caption{Table caption}

\begin{tabular}{
  S[table-format=-3.3]
  S[table-format=5.0]
  S[table-format=-3.3]
  S[table-format=1.5]
}
\toprule
{$t_0$ (\si{\mega\eV\femto\meter\cubed})} & 
{$t_3$ (\si{\mega\eV\femto\meter\tothe{6}})} &
{$v_0/\mu$ (\si{\mega\eV\femto\meter})} &
{$1/\mu$ (\si{\femto\meter})} \\
\midrule
-497.726 & 17270 & -166.924 & 0.45979\\
-497.726 & 17270 & -166.924 & 0.45979\\
-497.726 & 17270 & -166.924 & 0.45979\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I used `siunitx`, rather than math mode (which is wrong), for the units and also for correctly formatting data.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to resize your table if you use `makecell` (allows line breaks in cells) and `siunitx` for alignment of numeric data. Further, you'll obtain more professional-looking tables if you use only horizontal rules with `booktabs`. `Caption is loaded for a sensible vertical spacing for captions *above* tables.

```
\documentclass[12pt,leqno]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{siunitx, makecell, caption, booktabs}
\DeclareSIUnit \fm {\femto\meter}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering\sisetup{table-format=-3.3}
\setcellgapes{6pt}\makegapedcells
\caption{Table caption}
\begin{tabular}{|S|S[table-format=5]|S|S[table-format=1.5]|}
\hline
{\makecell{$t_0 $ \\ (\si{\MeV\cdot \fm^3 })}} & {\makecell{$t_3 $\\\si{(MeV\cdot fm^6)}}} & {\makecell{$v_0/\mu $\\(\si{\MeV\cdot \fm})}} & {\makecell{$1/\mu$\\(\si{\fm})}} \\
\hline
-497.726 & 17270 & -166.924 & 0.45979 \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!htbp]
\centering\sisetup{table-format=-3.3}
\caption{Table caption}
\begin{tabular}{SS[table-format=5]SS[table-format=1.5]}
\toprule
{\makecell{$t_0 $ \\ (\si{\MeV\cdot \fm^3 })}} & {\makecell{$t_3 $\\\si{(MeV\cdot fm^6)}}} & {\makecell{$v_0/\mu $\\(\si{\MeV\cdot \fm})}} & {\makecell{$1/\mu$\\(\si{\fm})}} \\
\midrule
-497.726 & 17270 & -166.924 & 0.45979 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm a bit confused. I need to resize the table because it's long and I need it to fit on one page. What part of your example code here is actually making the table content smaller?

Comment: I misunderstood your problem and thought your table was too wide. Does it really have to fit on one page? Anyway, `\resizebox` is a very bad solution for tables. You can try  changing the font size to `\small` or `\footnotesize`.

Comment: Instead of using a `tabular` environment and having to type lots of `$` symbols inside that environment, it would be better to use an `array` environment, as you'd have to type just 2 `$` symbols (before the start and after the end of the `array` env.)...

Comment: @Mico: I used  `$…$` only for the column heads. For the rest, it's up to `siunitx` to play.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the issue you're facing correctly, it's not that the tabular material is too wide but *too tall*, i.e., that it won't all fit *vertically* on a page. If this understanding is correct, do look into learning how to use the `longtable` environment.

An adaptation of your code to a `longtable` setting is shown below. It also uses the `\si` macro of the `siunitx` package to typeset scientific units according to internationally accepted (and required!) standards and the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package to give the table an "open" look.

At any rate, scaling (downsizing, really, of) an entire table just so that it fits on a page should be avoided like the plague.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx,booktabs,array,longtable}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}} % automatic math-mode version of "c"
\begin{document}
   \begin{longtable}{CCCC}
   %%% define headers and footers
   \caption{Table caption}\label{tab:long}\\
   \toprule
   t_0 & t_3 & v_0/\mu & 1/\mu\\[0.5ex]
   (\si{\mega\eV\femto\meter\cubed}) & (\si{\mega\eV\femto\meter\tothe{6}}) & 
   (\si{\mega\eV\femto\meter}) & (\si{\femto\meter})\\
   \midrule
   \endfirsthead
   %%
   \multicolumn{4}{l}{(Table \ref{tab:long}, continued)}\\
   \toprule
   t_0 & t_3 & v_0/\mu & 1/\mu\\[0.5ex]
   (\si{\mega\eV\femto\meter\cubed}) & (\si{\mega\eV\femto\meter\tothe{6}}) & 
   (\si{\mega\eV\femto\meter}) & (\si{\femto\meter})\\
   \midrule
   \endhead
   %%
   \midrule
   \multicolumn{4}{r}{(continued on following page)}\\
   \endfoot   
   %%
   \bottomrule
   \endlastfoot
   %%% body of longtable
   -497.726 & 17270 & -166.924 & 0.45979\\
   \end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you already see, resize tables left fonts inconsistencies in the document that are not good substitutes of a good table design. Unfortunately, your example of `tabular` is not a minimal `working` document, but guessing that is a standard `article` class (default margins, font size, etc.) the table take some less than 85% of the text width, so *the best solution in this is the case is do nothing* (at this respect only, of course, do no left the vertical rules, units in math mode, etc.).

If you really need change the natural width of the table, note that you can fix the maximum width in several ways, as using `p{}` columns and/or using the `tabular*` environment (note the asterisk) or the `tabularx` and `tabulary` environments of the respective packages, without changing the font size.

In general, to fit some large content in a fixed table width, your best options are:

1. Redesign the table (may be the best option).
2. Change the separations between columns (i.e, `\tabcolsep`).
3. Allow multiline cells (you have already this with `p{}`, `tabularx` and `tabulary` columns, in in other case, use a`\parbox` inside the  cells.)
4. As last resort, use `\small` or even `\foonotesize`, but do that as consistently as possible throughout the entire document. If that's not enough, forget the temptation of use smaller fonts and go to 1st point again.

The next is a example with `tabulary`. For simplicity the table and a dotted line showing the maximum allowed width is made with the macro `\taby`. Note that the first table have exactly the same width that using the normal `tabular` (less than 85% text width) but using `\tabcolsep` you can enlarge just to 85% with/without wrapping the headers, or shrink even at 70% without reducing the font. Only in case that the headers must be one line, a width of 70% need a smaller font.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,tabulary,fp}
% just for the example
\parindent0pt\parskip1em 
% just for lazyness
\let\Sc\textsuperscript  
\def\taby#1{% Argument is the maximum table width
\FPeval{\result}{round(#1*100,0)}
\makebox[#1\textwidth]{\dotfill \result{} \%\dotfill}\par
\begin{tabulary}{#1\textwidth}{*4{C}}
\toprule 
$t_0$ (MeV·fm\Sc3) & 
$t_3$ (MeV·fm\Sc6) &  
$v_0/\mu$ (MeV·fm) & 
$ 1/\mu$ (fm)\\\midrule
$-$497.726 &
17270 & 
166.924 & 
0.45979\\\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\par}

\begin{document}\centering

\taby{.85} 
{\tabcolsep.9em\taby{.85}}     
{\tabcolsep1em\taby{.85}}     
\taby{.75}     
{\footnotesize\tabcolsep1em \taby{.75}} 

\end{document}
```